# Facebook acc which using yahoo can't login to android app

Tags: android, facebook

In my application, can't login with yahoo facebook account(such as XXXXX@yahoo.com).Another mails(such as xxxx@gmail.com) are avaliable. When login button is clicked,it goes to facebook login page .After fill the mail and password, it can't go to another page... I don't know, what is going on? Here is my code which is get some facts and put another page....

```
       private class IDRequestListener implements RequestListener {

         @Override
        public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
            Log.d("Profile", response);
            String json = response;
            final String email;
            try {

               JSONObject profile = new JSONObject(json);
               final  String name = profile.getString("name");
               if( profile.getString("email").equals("")|| profile.getString("email").equals(null)){
                  email = "";
               }else{
                  email = profile.getString("email");
               }
               final String birth_day=profile.getString("birthday");
               final String gender=profile.getString("gender");
               Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main.class);
               i.putExtra("status", "facebook");
               i.putExtra("name", name);
               i.putExtra("email", email);
               i.putExtra("birthday", birth_day);
               i.putExtra("gender", gender);
               startActivity(i);

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Name: " + name + "\nEmail: " + email+ "Birthday"+birth_day + "Gender"+gender, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }

                });

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Edit: Some warning I got:

```
        03-24 06:43:57.445: W/com.facebook.Session(2305): Should not pass a read permission (email) to a request for publish or manage authorization
        03-24 06:43:57.445: W/com.facebook.Session(2305): Should not pass a read permission (user_birthday) to a request for publish or manage authorization
```

Edit: Logcat output..

```
03-25 11:06:13.165: I/Response(10980): {"work":[{"employer":{"id":"114476035259287","name":"not yet :)"}}],"birthday":"04\/01\/1990","locale":"en_US","link":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/thin.thaw","education":[{"type":"High School","year":{"id":"143018465715205","name":"2000"},"school":{"id":"114941651860886","name":"yes"}},{"type":"College","concentration":[{"id":"433384503391953","name":"Pyay Technology University"}],"school":{"id":"108061192547400","name":"Pyay Technological University"}}],"updated_time":"2013-03-15T11:58:43+0000","id":"100003374513765","first_name":"Thin","username":"thin.thaw","timezone":6.5,"verified":true,"name":"Thin Thaw","last_name":"Thaw","gender":"female"}
```

Comment: Is `onComplete` triggered?

Comment: Do you get the details? Did you debug the code after that?

Comment: No, I didn't debug.By the way, What is debug means.. ?

Comment: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: So, After debugging , May I solve my problem... ?

Comment: I dont know... but you should at least reach to the point where actual problem is!

Comment: I got some warning... Take a look..

Comment: what's the result of `Log.d("Profile", response);` ?

Comment: It only get some exception.(Err_name_not_resolved.) I think it concern with connection... :)